# How do I properly interact with the JSON return of twitter's API?

Tags: php, json, twitter

I'm using the Twitter API (version 1.1) and am trying to get a specific variable from the JSON return via PHP. **$mentions** is the returned **json_decode()** value of a [`GET statuses/mentions_timeline`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/mentions_timeline) request.

I have the following PHP:

```
foreach($mentions as $mention) {
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($mention) . "</pre><br>";
}
```

This works as expected, however when I add **['created_at']** to **$mention** I get:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

Expected return as per the [twitter docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/mentions_timeline):

```
[ // mentions
  { // mention
    "created_at": "Mon Sep 03 13:24:14 +0000 2012"
  }
]
```

This is an example of what's returned with **print_r($mention)** (inside the loop):

```
stdClass Object (
    [created_at] => Sat Apr 06 14:56:36 +0000 2013
)
```

Just what is this **stdClass** and how do I interact with it, if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$mentions = json_decode($data, true)
```

If you look in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), you will notice that there is `assoc` parameter if you want to get associative array instead of an object.

Otherwise you can access object properties with `$mention->created_at`

Comment: Thank you very much. While confused at the results, I tried `$mention->'created_at'` and apparently forgot to remove the quotes. Both methods work as expected.